# Greedy algorithm for finding independent set with max total weight complexity

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I have a grid graph $n \times n$ and all vertices have non-negative weights. I have a greedy algorithm below that finds an independent set with maximum total weight:

We scan all the vertices with non-ascending value of weight.
For each vertex that we place in our set, we remove its neighbours.

What complexity does this algorithm have? Can you explain to me?

Comment: Let $N = n ^2$ be the number of vertices.  Then you first need to sort the vertices by weight, which takes $N \log(N)$ time.  Then you go down the list and add heaviest possible vertices while throwing away the others.  This part can be done in linear time (because your graph has bounded degree, we don't even have to try hard to make this part go fast).  So in all, it's $N \log(N)$ to implement it the way I'm imagining, and you (essentially) have the sort the thing to do this in the way you describe anyway, so that's that.

Comment: (Of course, this greedy algorithm need not give you the best answer, but your graph is highly structured bipartite, so there's likely something optimal to do, and I wouldn't be surprised if it was connected to maximum matching sort of stuff.)